# What exactly are contentOffset& contentInset of ScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 questions about ScrollView. One is my major question, Another one is secondary confusion.

1.What exactly are `contentOffset` and `contentInset` of `ScrollView`? I will give more Details below.

2.I create a `ScrollView`, but it seems the `ScrollView` can't roll in any direction.Is the problem about offset? Or inset? I will give more Details below.

***Details for question 1:***

Sometimes `contentOffset` property and `contentInset` property seem to have lots of difference, but when I try to implement some of functions that relate to those two properties, I get confused.
And I make a simple illustration here. Can you help me figure it out that which part is offset and which part is inset?

[image]

***Details for question 2:***

I use following function to add a `ScrollView`

```
 func addScrollView(){
            // assign a new ScrollView to "scroll" class member 
            scroll = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectZero)
            scroll!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            // change it to gray color to help recognising 
            scroll!.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
            self.view.addSubview(scroll!)

            //add some constraints,[you can neglect following part]
            let x = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            self.view.addConstraint(x)

            let y = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1/2, constant: 25)
            self.view.addConstraint(y)

            let left = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.LeadingMargin, multiplier: 1, constant: 10)
            self.view.addConstraint(left)

            let upperSpacing = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 50)
            self.view.addConstraint(upperSpacing)

            let w = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 10)
            self.view.addConstraint(w)

            let h = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scroll!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: scroll!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
            self.view.addConstraint(h)
            print("add scroll view Successed")
        }
```

And it is not able to roll. It can only contain few things(Buttons or TextFields...) to fill its size, rather than put more things at places where we can't see.

So is the problem about setting outset & inset ? How can I set to fix this? And If I do so, how can I add things(buttons..) to the un-shown places programatically?

I hope you can tell me some things!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A few observations:

- The `contentOffset` is where the user has currently scrolled within the scroll view. This obviously changes as the user scrolls. You don't generally change this programmatically (unless you want to programmatically scroll somewhere, e.g. have a button to scroll to the top).
- The `contentInset` is how much the content is visually inset inside the scroll view (i.e. what the "margins" within the scrollview are). You generally set this once in IB or in `viewDidLoad`, as the scroll view is instantiated.
- The `contentSize` is how big the scrollable content is. Note, with autolayout, you don't have to specify this manually, but rather is calculated by the constraints that you specified between the scroll view and its subviews (and the constraints for the subviews and between the subviews).

To get scrolling to work correctly, it is a combination of (a) the `bounds` of the scroll view, less any `contentInset`; and (b) the `contentSize`, as calculated for you from the constraints of the subviews.

Comment: Hi Rob! Thank you ! And I can follow first 2. But to simplify 3rd one, I want to confirm that dose "scrollable content" simply mean the scrollView's size?

Comment: No, by "scrollable content" I was referring to all of the subviews of the scroll view. And if all of those subviews have their constraints fully defined, then the scroll view's `contentSize` will be calculated and set for you. So let's imagine that your scroll view was 480 points tall, but the height (as dictated by constraints) of all of its subviews and their spacing added up to 700 points (`contentSize.height` is 700), then you would be able to scroll that 700 points of content up and down within the 480 point scroll view.

Answer (score 11):

`contentOffset` indicates the current position of the scroll view content, relative to the origin coordinates on the top-left corner. You shouldn't programmatically set this value unless you would like to programmatically adjust the scroll position.

`contentInset` allows to specify margins around the content in the scrollview. You can specify the margin programmatically as follows:

```
scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 7.0)
```

Comment: Hi ! Eneko Alonso !Thank your answer at first! I want to ask that programmatically set the inset is intent to make a smaller area for user to view the content. Am I right?

Comment: @Microos, good question. It'll be great if we know the answer as well!

Comment: @Microos, correct, setting the `contentInset` to values greater than zero will add "padding" around the content view. For example, this is good in cases where you want to have some merging between the content and edges of screen: you could set left and right insets to 10-20px

Answer (score 0):

Question is old, but regarding to your second problem, you should use contentSize, not offset and inset.

```
  let contentWidth = 400 //or any other value that suits you
  let contentHeight = 50 
  scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: contentHeight)
```

If content is smaller than either one of dimensions, it will scroll vertically or horizontally, depending of proportions.

Regards